# Does Cytoscape have a silent/unattended uninstall command?

Tags: cytoscape

Im trying to build an automation script for my environment to install the newest version of cytoscape and uninstall its older version, Does cytoscape have a command line prompt to silently uninstall that older version?

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer;

use the install4j -q option with the uninstaller to uninstall silently